# calling methods that do not exist yet java

Tags: java

I am trying to make automated error handling in java. Some one else could call my error handling method and it handles the errors for them. I am attempting to have it so if the class calling my method had a close() method I could call it and it would close everything preventing resource leaks. I tried something like this:

```
public void logError(Error e, Object obj){
  obj.close();
}
```

The only problem is this will not run because object by default does not have a close() method. I could create my own object and have their class extend it but it would not work if they wanted to extend a different class.

Comment: If you *really* want to do this, then you should check out Reflection (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/).

Comment: You can create an interface that any class that wants to use your logError method must implement.

Comment: I don't think that this would be a good idea. If you really want to, look into reflection.

Comment: Would using a `try-finally` use `Closeable` if the object implements it? It should, I think.

Comment: If what you're trying to do is log the error (as your method name implies), then log it.  Leave it to the caller whether or not to close the object.

Comment: This is bad ... don't do this. This doesn't help anyone

Comment: I like @OldProgrammer's solution (create an interface). Note though that if you think of also providing an overloaded `logError()` which takes an `Object` so they can also pass in other objects that don't implement the interface, you may run into pitfalls -- in particular the choice of which `logError()` overload gets called will be determined statically at compile time, not polymorphically at runtime. So beware of that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need an interface:

```
interface Closeable {
   public void close();
}
```

Otherwise you could inspect the Object via reflection.

Comment: How would I make the parameter for the method require implementation of closeable. I tried public void logError(Error e, Closeable obj) but that just expects a class extending Closeable

Comment: If Closeable is an interface then it will expect a class implementing the interface. If it expects something extending Closeable then your Closeable is not an interface but a class.

Comment: `Closeable` *is* already an interface. So I would not suggest defining your own, but instead use the already defined one.

Comment: The already defined one was not working well, I made my own and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a design issue if you're closing resources in a logging method.  As others have mentioned, use an interface and handle closing the resource elsewhere.

If you really want to proceed with this approach, you need to use reflection.  The invoke call below will throw some exceptions that you'll need to catch.

```
public void logError(Error e, Object obj)
{
    Method closeMethod = obj.getClass().getMethod("close", null)
    if (closeMethod != null)
        closeMethod.invoke(obj, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following:

```
public void logError(Error e, Closeable obj) {
    //do your logging
    obj.close();
}
```

---

```
public void logError(Error e, Object obj){
    //do your logging
    Method closeMethod = obj.getClass().getMethod("close", null);
    if (closeMethod != null) {
        //log that the method has a .close() method, but does NOT implement Closeable
    }
}
```

This will ensure that first your logging will attempt to close a `Closeable` object. If that fails, it will fall back to the general `Object` implementation. And I have added reflection here *only* to do additional logging, it is not neccessary to use reflection at all in here and I think that you should not be calling `close()` manually on an object that does *not* implement `Closeable`.

For method overloading precedence refer to: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2

The answer should work as any object is more specific as `Object`, as long as it adds something to the functionality.